# If S is a 1-dimensional subspace and T is a 2-dimensional subspace of the vector space of 2 × 4 matrices over R then S ∪ T is also a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

I know this statement is false, but how can I explain it and give counter example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You can think of the matrix

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}x_{1}&x_{2}&x_{3}&x_{4}\\x_{5}&x_{6}&x_{7}&x_{8}\end{pmatrix}$$

as the vector

$$v=\begin{pmatrix}x_{1}\\x_{2}\\x_{3}\\x_{4}\\x_{5}\\x_{6}\\x_{7}\\x_{8}\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus your vector space is in fact just $V\cong\mathbb{R}^{8}$, which is more familiar. Can you think of an example now?

Comment: I got stuck in notation S ∪ T. How should I show it?

Comment: @J.Smith What are your doubts about this notation? This is the union of the set $S$ and the set $T$. For example, if $S$ is a line and $T$ is another line, then $S\cup T$ is both lines.